# Can anyone tell me anything about "The James" bicycles?

Tags: vintage

[image][image]Recently we were donated a bike with a logo stating "The James." I am trying to find some information on this bike. It is a three speed bike. The gear system says "Sturmey Archer." There is writing that says "made in England." I can't find any picture of it online or article that can provide me with any information concerning origin or value. Thanks for any help that you may be able to offer!

Comment: I would estimate the vintage as somewhere between 1955 and 1970.  I suspect the seat has been replaced.

Comment: That is a Loverly bike - and I'd bet it rides really nicely.   I've worked on other similar-vintage bikes and they all had a particularly stable and predictable geometry that has largely vanished.  She's a keeper.

Comment: Sturmey Archer was a prolific manufacturer of hub gears for bicycles. If you examine the hub you may be able to find a model (e.g. 'AW') and date code on it. See https://sheldonbrown.com/english-3.html#sturmey

Comment: I found a similar bike, the advertiser values it at £95
https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/284908380805

Comment: The hub should have a two digit number stamped on it which will be the year of production eg 57 for 1957. Almost all of them have this. As it is very likely that the wheel is original, this will give you the year the bike was manufactured, or very close.

Comment: I am reminded that, back in the 50s and 60s, "English racer" bikes were popular with older kids (especially girls) in many parts of the US.  The above picture depicts what would have been called an English racer -- rim brakes, geared rear hub, et al.

Answer (score 9):

If "The James" means The James Cycle Co Ltd, of England;

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Cycle_Co)

> The James Cycle Co Ltd., Greet, Birmingham, England, was one of many British cycle and motorcycle makers based in the English Midlands, particularly Birmingham. Most of their light motorcycles, often with the characteristic maroon finish, used Villiers and, later, AMC two-stroke engines.
>
> James were prolific bicycle and motorcycle manufacturers from 1897 to 1966. The company was taken over by Associated Motor Cycles in 1951 and combined with Francis-Barnett in 1957. In 1966 the company became one of the many British motorcycle companies forced out of business by Japanese competition.

There is more detailed information along with a variety of advertisements showing bicycles and motorcycles at [Grace's Guide To British Industrial History](https://www.gracesguide.co.uk/James_Cycle_Co)

Here is an ad from 1936 as an example:
[image]

Comment: The text "James Cycle Co Ltd" is seen in the upper left of the badge photographed, so you're on the right track.